# Azure iothub Device twin throwing InternalServerError with golang

Tags: azure, internal-server-error

I have been using https://github.com/tappoz/azure-golang-iothub/ to read a device twin from azure iothub. Since yesterday it stopped working and giving me this error:
{"Message":"ErrorCode:ServerError;InternalServerError","ExceptionMessage":"Tracking ID:bd8489a3048d4fa3b7c655d2e5ea57a5-G:10-TimeStamp:03/20/2019 18:32:26"} 500 Internal Server Error

Any idea why it stopped working since yesterday and/or how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft changed how Shared Access Signature is supposed to be computed. It used to take
".azure-devices.net/devices/?api-version=2016-11-14" for the computation, since March 18/19, the new way of computing would take just the "".azure-devices.net/devices/" part. I will submit a change to  https://github.com/tappoz/azure-golang-iothub/ accordingly